# How to test significance in questionnaire answers from 0 to 10

Tags: r, statistics

I am currently generating a panel dataset with random numbers. I simulate a questionnaire where "people" get to answer on a scale of 0 to 10 with 10 being the best. Creating the data was neasy. I used this to get answers where I assume that the average answer would be around 7.

variable <- rbinom(n, 10, 0.70)

Now in the panel  data I want to create fluctuations in later periods, which is also not too difficult jut changing the probability parameter and then compare them to a historical mean to infer whether the change in wellbeing is statistically different.

So my question is: What test do I conduct hypothetically in a real scenario? Since people can only answer from 0 to 10 it is not really normally distributed, however I can choose n to be very high. T-test? And what about confidence intervals?

I know that the data is not continuous and that a mean of 6.942 doesn't exist because it is not defined. I neglect this basing my decision on a paper I read. There they choose to treat the scores as contiuous variables for simplification purposes. I have read in other threads that there are super sophisticated approaches for evaluating this kind of stuff. The paper then shows graphs where certain events triggered a decline in wellbeing that was statistically significant but the version I have does not go into detail on how they conducted the significance test.

Any help is massively appreciated!

Comment: Interesting question, however, since it's a conceptual question, it's off topic in this forum; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to know from the test, eg. what is the specific question you are asking? If the *mean is different* ?

Perhaps the *Mann-Whitney U test* would suffice if you feel mean's aren't really of value to you? It answers a slightly different question: "Would you expect one population to have higher values than another", which still sounds applicable to your case.

```r
set.seed( 100 )
n <- 50
ref.data <- rbinom(n, 10, 0.70)
new.data <- rbinom(n, 10, 0.60)
wilcox.test( ref.data, new.data, paired=FALSE )
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. No I was generally interested if a certain event has a significant negative effect on wellbeing. So basically Imagine a mean wellbeing of 7.5 and then there is a natural disaster and the measurements of this period show a mean wellbeing of 6. I want to test whether 6 is statistically different from 7.5. Basically I do t.test and construct confidence intervals which is all no problem to me but I wonder if it is statistically correct in thise case as the data is not really t distributed, or normally dsitributed. Or is it? My n can be super high like 5000 per period

Comment: But the Mann Whitney U test sounds interesting! I could probably compare emplyed to unemployed groups or compare gender differences. I will read into it!